# Which is the correct F-beta-measure scoring formula?

Tags: measurement, model-evaluation, metric, f-statistic

I have found differing formulas to calculate the $Fbeta$ score, which changes the weight (influence) of $PPV$ ($Precision$) or $TPR$ ($Recall$) from the default of equality (i.e. $0.5$).

For example:

$Fb = 1 + ( fbeta * fbeta ) ) * ( ( PPV * TPR ) / ( ( ( fbeta * fbeta ) * PPV ) + TPR )$

$Fb = 1 / ( fbeta * ( 1 / PPV ) + (1 - fbeta ) * ( 1 / TPR ) )$

Where $fbeta$ is your any value between $0.0$ and $1.0$; $0.5$ would denote equality; values to either side of $0.5$ would (or should) bias the $F1$-score to either $recall$ or $precision$.

Is there a "correct" formula?  What are the effective differences between these formulas?  They both appear to "work" but produce differing values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct formula, or at least, the one which works as expected is:

$Fb = 1 / ( fbeta * ( 1 / PPV ) + (1 - fbeta ) * ( 1 / TPR ) )$

Where $fbeta$ weight is specified as a value between $0.0$ and $1.0$:

$0.0$ to $0.5$ gives weight to $Recall$.

$0.5$ is equal weight between $Precision$ and $Recall$ (i.e. the standard $F1$).

$0.5$ to $1.0$ gives weight to $Precision$.

Comment: what happens when $\beta $ goes past one? like 2 making it F2-score or more? will more weight be given to precision?